# iphone-Page-Navigation-on-uitableview

Tags: iphone

i make one form which display Diamonds primary detail
when i select Single row  ,page is navigate to second Page "Detail page"
which show the full detail of Selected Diamond..
(I Use Single UITableViewCell Display Full Detail Of Diamond)

FirstPage To Navigate From Second. My Code Is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {

    self.DiamondDetail = [[DiamondDetail alloc] init];
    DimEntity *Dim = [DimArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _DiamondDetail.Diamond = Dim;
    self.title = @"    Detail    ";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: _DiamondDetail animated:YES];

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; 
}
```

Now ,, Output Of Detail Page
On NavigationBar Left Side There Is One Button Automatically Generated Say "    Detail   "
When Click That Button Page Is Again Navigate To First Page..

But..

I Want..

When User Move His/Her Finger On IPad-IPhone Surface / UITableviewCell

From Right To Left Then also Page Should Be Navigate..

How I Can

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to study about [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];

        // Swipe Left
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];

        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
        [swipeLeft release];

        // Swipe Right
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];

        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
        [swipeRight release];
    }   
- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
 [self.navigationController pushViewController: _DiamondDetail animated:YES]
}

- (void)handleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
[self.navigationController pushViewController: _DiamondDetail animated:YES]
}
```

Comment: hello thanx for this help,, But I Want To,,,,,,, From _DiamondDetail Page To ResultPage(UITableView Which Display Multiple Diamonds) Navigation Then How