# iphone-page-navigation-on-uitableview

Tags: iphone

I Ask Question Of Below Link,, And I Got Answer

[iphone-Page-Navigation-on-uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962894/iphone-page-navigation-on-uitableview)

Thanx For That..

But I Want To Navigate From Second Page To First Page..

Means..

From DiamondDetail Page To ResultPage(Which Show Multiple Diamonds)
i.e. SecondPage->First Page.. Then How Can ?

You Were Send Me Coading Of ... 
From ResultPage To DiamondDetail Page..
i.e. Firstpage->SecondPage..

Comment: do u mean popViewController??

Answer (score 0):

Make use of

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```